# How to construct this query to show first the desired rows and then the rest?

Tags: php, mysql

In my page I show some entries based on the range of the chosenTime a user chosen to get contacted, and saved it into mySQL.

I have 4 range groups of times (our working times 09:00-17:00) that a user can select from

```
09:00 - 11:00
11:00 - 13:00
13:00 - 15:00
15:00 - 17:00
```

For now, I show the results as below, order by the chosenTime

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table order by chosenTime asc";
```

What I want to do is to sort the results based on the current time.

For example if time is 10:30, show first the rows that the chosen time is between 09:00-11:00. If it is 11:00, show first the 11:00 - 13:00 results.

I am thinking about a between but I don't know on how to proceed with this.

--**What I did so far**--

My "dirty" try is this. Because it is hard to compare these data because of the format, I created a time like

```
 $current = date("Hi", strtotime('+3 hours'));
```

so this gives me a **1330**

After this

```
if  ($current < "1059")  { 

show the results in the default way, chosenTime asc

} else
if (($current >"1100") && ($current < "1259")) { 

show the results starting with the ones that chosenTime="11:00 - 13:00" and then
 continue to the 13-15, 15-17, 09-11

} else
if (($current >"1300") && ($current < "1459")) { 

this follows the above example starting with chosenTime="13:00 - 15:00"

} else
if (($current >"1500") && ($current < "1659")) { 

this follows the above example starting with chosenTime="15:00 - 17:00"

}
```

The problem is how do I construct that query?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `case when` clause in `order by` on the `$current` value and decide the sort order column.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
order by 
  case when '$current' < 1100 then 0                 -- default order
       when '$current' between 1100 and 1300 then 1  -- 09:00 - 11:00 
       when '$current' between 1301 and 1500 then 2  -- 11:00 - 13:00 
       when '$current' between 1501 and 1700 then 3  -- 13:00 - 15:00 
       when '$current' between 1701 and 1900 then 4  -- 15:00 - 17:00
  end
```

Comment: I am trying to understand what you proposed. Can you be a little more descriptive after the `then` ?

Comment: Suppose your selection is like `select 9_2_11, 11_2_13,...` then, in the `order by` clause `1` stands for the 1st column and the `2` stands for the 2nd column *selected* in the query. `0` stands for none and hence becomes default.

Comment: If the `$current` is `1450` then the results are sorted by column `2` i.e. `11_2_13`.

Comment: I can't follow. the chosenTime is one field that contains the chosen range time by the user. I have tried the code but all I get is the results sorted by id

Comment: How are these time values stored in database? A single string like `11:00 - 13:00` or two different values `11:00` and `13:00` into 2 columns, say `from_time` and `to_time`?

Comment: it is a signle string as you said